# Durability of string's reverse iterators for self appending

Tags: c++, string, iterator, language-lawyer

#### The question:

Suppose I have a string, and I want to generate a new string that has the original string and its reverse concatenated.

Is the following guaranteed to work?

```
auto pq = [](std::string &s){
    s.reserve(2*s.size());
    s.append(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
};
```

I see that `reserve` is supposed to set `capacity` appropriately. But, does applying `append` against the reverse iterators cause invalidation of those iterators?

#### Additional background:

My copy for C++.11 (which has the same language as the [C++.17 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)), says in §[string.capacity]

> **`void reserve(size_type res_arg=0);`**
>
> 10. The member function `reserve()` is a directive that informs a `basic_string` object of a planned change
>       in size, so that it can manage the storage allocation accordingly.
> 11. *Effects:* After `reserve()`, `capacity()` is greater or equal to the argument of reserve. [ *Note:* Calling
>       `reserve()` with a `res_arg` argument less than `capacity()` is in effect a non-binding shrink request.
>       A call with `res_arg <= size()` is in effect a non-binding shrink-to-fit request. — *end note* ]
> 12. *Throws:* length_error if `res_arg > max_size()`.<sup>227</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>227) <kbd>reserve()</kbd> uses <kbd>allocator_traits::allocate()</kbd> which may throw an appropriate exception.</sup>

While, §[string.append] says

> **`basic_string&`
>
>       `append(const charT* s, size_type n);`**
>
> 11. *Requires:* `s` points to an array of at least `n` elements of `charT`.
> 12. *Throws:* `length_error` if `size() + n > max_size()`.
> 13. *Effects:* The function replaces the string controlled by `*this` with a string of length `size() + n`
>       whose first `size()` elements are a copy of the original string controlled by `*this` and whose remaining
>       elements are a copy of the initial `n` elements of `s`.
> 14. *Returns:* `*this`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, as long as the capacity is great enough, that iterators are not invalidated when appending to strings and that this would extend to reverse iterators; if I'm right this code will generate a palidrome. But I'm definitely not certain of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the overload of `std::string::append` you actually call. The one you call is [`template<class InputIterator> basic_string& append(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.append#19). There, the standard says ([[string.append]/21](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/string.append#21)) it is equivalent to constructing a new string before appending:

> Effects: Equivalent to `append(basic_­string(first, last, get_­allocator()))`.

Note that here, the constructor call `basic_­string(first, last, get_­allocator())` creates a temporary string *before* the call to a different overload of `append`, so whatever re-allocation happens in the other `append` is irrelevant. That means that, even without calling `reserve` first, this should be safe.

Note that there is no guarantee that string is implemented exactly this way; the standard says "Equivalent to", not "Implemented as". The implementation can do anything which has the same results, but in this case "the same results" means that it still needs to work with iterators derived from the same string this is called on.

Comment: @jxh if these quotes from the standard are correct, there are *three* calls in play here. The first with two iterators constructs a new string, then calls the second with that string, which then calls the third with the string data and length. No contradictions.

Comment: @jxh Note that there is no guarantee that the calls are exactly as specified; as I pointed out elsewhere, libstdc++ implements this actual call using `std::string::replace` instead of with a different overload of `append`. The standard guarantees that the visible effects are the same, so this should work.

Comment: Updated my answer to explain these details there, not just in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I do not believe this answer is correct anymore, see comments. But for the sake of preserving valuable comments I am leaving the answer there.

The most straightforward of append would look something like:

```
template<class T>
void string::append(T begin, T end) {
    reserve(size() + std::distance(end, begin));
    while (; begin != end; ++begin) {
       *this += *begin;
    }
}
```

Since iterators should not be invalidated after the reserve, begin will still be valid for dereferencing and incrementing during the whole function.

In the example above, `reserve` is guaranteed to be no-op from the latest draft I have access to (http://eel.is/c++draft/string.capacity):

> (24.3.2.4) void reserve(size_type res_arg);
>
> #Effects: A directive that informs a basic_­string of a planned change in size, so that the storage allocation can be managed accordingly.
>   After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of
>   reserve if reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of
>   capacity() otherwise. Reallocation happens at this point if and only
>   if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve()

Comment: It's a violation of the ODR to redefine `std::string::append`, and why would you want to?

Comment: @DanielH where did he state that he wants to? He simply provided the most probable implementation - not proposed to implement it himself

Comment: @Fureeish Oh, I misread the answer. In that case, going based on the most likely implementation can be misleading. For example, libstdc++ implements the iterator-based append [in terms of `std::string::replace`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L1291), which does not have the same guarantees as this code sample.

Comment: Is there really a guarantee that the call to `reserve()` will be a no-op?

Comment: @jxh under which circumstances?

Comment: @jxh I am not sure what is the source of your reading. Quoting standard: `void reserve(size_type res_arg);
#Effects: A directive that informs a basic_­string of a planned change in size, so that the storage allocation can be managed accordingly. After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of capacity() otherwise. Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve().`

Comment: @jxh I do not have access to this one, so  can't comment or compare. I would imagine even back than it would be considered a defect in standard to omit this part.

Comment: Can you add your citation to your answer, and a link to the source?

Comment: Done, added, quoted.

Comment: Note that the iterators passed to `append` are *input* iterators, so it wouldn't be possible to take the `distance` before using them.

Comment: @jxh since the spec says that `append` takes input iterators, any implementation that requires random access iterators would be non-conforming. You have to code to the lowest common denominator, so the example code in this answer wouldn't be suitable even if it would work for your specific case.

Comment: @MarkRansom good point, didn't think about it. At this point, I would delete my answer altogether, but I think it has valuable discussion in comments, so I will just edit it to that effect.

Comment: @jxh can't work for input iterators, as they could easily be single pass (for example, iostream input iterators are single-pass iterators)

Comment: @MarkRansom It is relatively common to use tag dispatch on `typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category` to figure out what kind of iterator you have, and do things more efficiently if possible.